# Solaris 10 app server operating on two company domains

Tags: domain-name, hosts, solaris-10, resolv.conf

I have a Solaris server hosting Apache and Tomcat web servers, it originally operated on one company domain:
appname1.company1.com

With a change in company, this original domain must still be maintained and a new one must operate in parallel:
appname1.company2.com

In addition the server has a unique internal host name that nominates it:
server.nom.sys

The namespace entry for company2 was created recently and added into the Apache config files for the www hosts and all this side appears to be operating correctly.

Within Tomcat the config is only referring to the localhost, however there now appears to be a problem where servlets / webapps not finding files as a result.

From my understanding I will need to update the hosts and resolv.conf files to fix this, but I have not been able to identify how to do this so that the name and address entries are correctly nominated for both company domains.

The original resolv.conf is as follows...

```
domain nom.sys
nameserver  (company1 nameserver 1 IP)
nameserver  (company1 nameserver 2 IP)
search company1.com nom.sys
```

And the hosts file relevant lines are as follows...

```
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.238.142.173 server123 server123.nom.sys  loghost
10.238.142.74   zoneserv1 loghost zoneserv1.ad.sys
```

Apologies if this has been asked before, I have searched in ServerFault and Google for an answer but to no avail - assistance is much appreciated.